# Replace Default PK slug with Multiple Lookup Fields for ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, slug, model-view, lookupfield

I have two slugs, against which I run queries. Thanks to base class `MultipleFieldLookupMixin`, which my view class is inherited from and thus allows me to have multiple `lookup_fields`.

We know that when `ModelViewSet` is used with `DefaultRouter`, **appends a `pk` at the end of URL**, **which I don't want**.

For example, when I do this:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'organization', OrganizationModelViewSet, basename='organization')


urlpatterns = [
    path('viewset/<str:device>/<str:start_time>/', include(router.urls))
]
```

it gives me the URL

```
mydomain.com/viewset/<str:device>/<str:start_time>/organization/<int:pk>/
```

I don't want this `pk` at the end. If we can remove `organization`, that's even better. I want the endpoint to be,

`mydomain.com/<str:device>/<str:start_time>/`.

More playing around, I learned that adding `extra_kwargs` like this in my `serializer` class,

```
    extra_kwargs = {
        'url': {'lookup_field': 'start_time'}
    }
```

and modify `lookup_fields` in view class, with singular lookup field, like `lookup_field`, with value let's say, `start_time`, as shown

```
lookup_fields = ["device", "start_time"]
```

with

```
lookup_field = "start_time"
```

and also modify the URL accordingly by removing the `start_time` slug, then URL becomes

```
mydomain.com/viewset/<str:device>/organization/<str:start_time>/
```

Modifying singular `lookup_field` with `start_time`, apparently gives us more or less the desired URL, but doesn't get the job done because we have a single lookup_field now!

If we edit this line

```
router.register(r'organization', DeviceActivityModelViewSet, basename='device_activity')
```

to

```
router.register(r'', DeviceActivityModelViewSet, basename='device_activity')
```

then we get the URL

```
mydomain.com/viewset/<str:device>/<str:start_time>/
```

which is exactly what I want, but still as I said, it doesn't work, because of the single lookup field.

Cutting to the chase, I hope it clarifies my research into this and I restate my problem statement that I want to have this URL endpoint

`mydomain.com/<str:device>/<str:start_time>/`.

with two slugs, without changing the base class for my view i.e `ModelViewSet`. I know the functionality I want can be easily done with `GenericAPIView` and I also have done it, but I am curious how to do it this way.

Comment: What happens if you keep `lookup_fields = ["device", "start_time"]` but use `router.register(r''`?

Comment: @bdbd to change the last slug, which is "pk", we not only need to add `kwargs_url` dictionary with `lookup_field` but also need to add exactly same `lookup_field` in views. That's why I changed `lookup_fields` in views with `lookup_field` and changed its value to `startup_time`. If they don't match, the URL remains as it is:
`mydomain.com/viewset/<str:device>/<str:start_time>/organization/<int:pk>/`

If I add `lookup_fields` in `extra_kwargs` like, 
`extra_kwargs = { 'url': {'lookup_fields': ['device', 'start_time']}}`
it doesn't work either and URL remains as above mentioned

Comment: Can you add the `MultipleFieldLookupMixin` definition? Also this sounds like perfect use case for custom router implementation. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#custom-routers

Comment: Please show the code for **`OrganizationModelViewSet`**

Answer (score 1):

As i don't have to full view of your code so I think below code snippet should work for you.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/<str:device>/<str:start_time>/', include(router.urls))
]
```

If it didn't work then please let me know